# How were the particles created from the vacuum state, in the beginning of the universe?

Tags: energy-conservation, universe, big-bang, vacuum, matter

1. How were the particles created from the vacuum state, in the beginning of the universe?
2. If the particles are created when some energy is supplied to vacuum state, then how were particles created?
3. What was the external source of energy that created particles out of the field if field is the elementary thing?